# Screen off in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried to test my application in android emulator, but could not test it in case when the screen is go off (battery safe mode) but application is still alive (perform some computation), is there any flags for the emulator to emulate this behavior (screen off)?

Answer (score 2):

```
private Window wind;

wind = this.getWindow();
        wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_OFF);
```

try this.